# How can I rebuild an AJAX Request in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, parsing

First of all: I don't know anything about AJAX or similar. Please keep that in mind.

Question is above. I am trying to parse information from a website (http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/). More specific: I want to parse the information which is held by the `<table id="nextMatches_0">`. I found out that this is not possible with the Library I used until now: Jsoup, because the website gets the information from outside. Until now I think that it's AJAX which is fillig in the table.

Though I didn't find a way to parse the information I want, it would be great to just make the same thing the website does and send a request to the server. But I don't have a clue how I could do this, which is why I am asking for help.

Big thanks already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to reverse engineer how some data gets into a web page so you can figure out how you can get that same data from your Javas app.  So far, you've concluded that the data itself is not in the HTML so your guess is that some script in the web page is putting the data into the page via an Ajax call.

First off, to confirm whether that is the case, you can do two things:

1. Bring up that page in the web browser and do View/Source.  Examine the original HTML of the page and see if the content you want is in there.  If it is, then you can just do a direct request from the server to get that page, parse the HTML and then grab your content.  If the content you want is not in the original HTML of the page, then go to step 2.
2. Open the Chrome debugger.  Switch to the network tab.  Then, load your page into the browser.  Examine the requests in the network tab and find all the request that list their "type" as "xhr".  These will be the ajax requests from that page.  I see at least 3 xhr requests in that page.  Then examine each xhr request to see if it is the one requesting and receiving the specific data you are interested in.  If you find it, then you can study how the request is formed to see if you can send that same request to the same source from your Java app.

If, in the first step you find the data is actually in the HTML, then you can just request that link from your Java, get the HTML, put it into an HTML parser and then find the content you want in the parsed page.

If, in the second step, you conclude there is an Ajax call that is fetching the data you want, then you need to see how the request is formed and what host it is sent to and copy that type of request from your Java app to see if you can obtain the same data.  I see that page contains a couple Ajax calls that are fetching JSON.  If one of those is what you want, then you would parse the JSON in your Java app so you could then access the data from your Java code.

---

Oh, and I'd suggest reading the licensing information on the site to see what you are actually allowed to do with someone else's content or Ajax calls.

Comment: Ok so I have this done now, but I did it in a bit different way, I just used the link I found out through the Developer Tools ... unfortunately, now I need to get the information from a website like this: http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/mainz-wolfsburg-ILlyHUXf/ which is individually built each time. So it doesn't have a static link which I can use all the time. Do you have any idea how i could probably get the information I need now ? I can't describe it really good, if you need more information for this, just say and i'll provide it.

Comment: @njoye - the proper procedure here on StackOverflow is for you to describe your new problem in a new question, not to try to continue this question for a new issue.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. Will do.